# Can I use logical operators with function paramenters?

Tags: c++, function, variables, parameters, logical-operators

I want to create a function, where you can either use an `int` or a `string` variable as an parameter, but I don't know how.

I am writing a little example of what I want to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int function((int a) || (string a))
{
    ...;
}

int main()
{
    int intvar;
    string stringvar;

    function(intvar);
    function(stringvar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assume that is possible, how are you going to write *the function-body* in a meaningful way?  Is `a  % 2` allowed in the function-body?

Comment: The thing is I can't do that. I've tried that and it didn't worked. I've just typed that as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Can I use logical operators with function paramenters?

No, you can't.

What you basically want is a function template or overload. The latter is the simplest way:

```
int function(int a)
{
    // ...;
}

int function(string a)
{
    // ...;
}
```

In case you have the same code for the varying types use a template:

```
template<typename T>
int function(T a)
{
    static_assert(std::is_convertible<T,int>() || std::is_convertible<T,std::string>());
    // ...;
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew that you can write the same function twice. Thanks!

Comment: @SaJmoN you can read about `is_same` here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: @SauravSahu OP referred to the overloaded function version (check the edit history).

Comment: Actually, the second example would be inconvenient. It prevents you from calling `function` with an argument that's _convertable_  to `int` or `std::string`. You solve it by having the two function definitions of the first example, _and_ having `template <typename T> int funtion_impl(T a)` in the .cpp file so you can share the implementation. (One of the rare reasons why you'd see templates in an implementation file)

Comment: @MSalters Fixed that. THX for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to overload the function and call one from the other, something like:

```
int function(int a) {
    // handle int parameter
}

int function(const string& s) {
    int a = stoi(s);
    return function(a);
}
```